# ROBLOX Combat System Script - Syntax Error: Expected ')' to close '(' at line 7), got ','

Tags: lua, syntax-error, roblox

This is the script I'm using. Got It from this YouTube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jLFegVaNByI.
I've checked and tried to solve this multiple times, can't find my mistake.

Roblox Studio PrtScrn:

[image: 1]

```
local RP = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local Combat = RP:WaitForChild("Combat")

local Animations = script:WaitForChild("Animations")

local anims = 
    (
        Animations:WaitForChild("RightPunch"), -- error is here.
        Animations:WaitForChild("LeftKnee"),
        Animations:WaitForChild("LeftPunch"),
        Animations:WaitForChild("RightKnee"),
        Animations:WaitForChild("StrongKick"),
    )

Combat.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player,count)
    local Character = player.Character
    local Humanoid = Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    
    local Attack = Humanoid:LoadAnimation(anims[count])
    Attack:Play()
    
    Combat:FireClient(player)
end)
```

Comment: The script is supposed to produce a combo of 5 attacks, and the error is at the anims table.

Comment: `anims` should be enclosed in `{}`, not `()` - it's a table.

Comment: And the last element in line 12 of the table ends with a ```,```  - Delete it

Comment: @koyaanisqatsi that's perfectly fine and common practice. why go through the trouble of managing the last commas when adding or removing table entries. trailing commas are ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lua tables are created using the table constructor `{}`.

The error message is caused by `local anims = (Animations:WaitForChild("RightPunch"),`

because `(expr,` is invalid syntax. You cannot have a comma separated list inside parentheses `()`.

Instead of the expected `)` Lua will find a `,` and complain about it.

But you shouldn't use `(` in the first place so that error is just a symptom of your actual mistake.

So the thought process here is:

Why does Lua want me to put a `)` where I need a `,` to separate table items ? And why should that `)` close `(` in line 7? I don't need `(` there, this is not how you create a table.